# Set vertical spacing between two particular items

Tags: math-mode, spacing, itemize

Please consider the following list:

```
There is a $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ with
\begin{itemize}
    \item $K_n$ is compact;
    \item $K_n\subseteq\overset\circ K_{n+1}$; and
    \item $d(\partial K_n,\partial K_{n+1})>0$
\end{itemize}
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
```

This doesn't render well:

[image: render]

There's too much vertical empty space between the first and the second item (due to the circle above K). I would like to set the vertical spacing between these two items to 0pt, but I only know how I can set the vertical spacing between all items or between all items starting from a particular item.

So, how can we do this? Or would you recommend an other solution? Maybe it would be better to use only symbols which don't extend vertically inside a list. How is this usually done? Do you use $K^\circ$ instead? Or $\operatorname{int} K$? I don't like the latter and my problem with $K^\circ$ is that it's not consistent with other occurences in my document where I've used $\overset\circ K$.

Comment: Adjust vertical space manually with \\[-1.5ex] at the end of each \item. Change 1.5 to get desired results.

Comment: @jak123 Why at the end of *each* item?

Comment: Each item you would like to adjust. And its \\ not \ as I wrote before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\smash{\overset\circ K_{n+1}}` to hide the height of that element.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
There is a $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ with
\begin{itemize}
    \item $K_n$ is compact;
    \item $K_n\subseteq\smash{\overset\circ K_{n+1}}$; and
    \item $d(\partial K_n,\partial K_{n+1})>0$
\end{itemize}
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have this problem if you use the `\mathring` accent:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
There is a $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ with
\begin{itemize}
    \item $K_n$ is compact;
    \item $K_n\subseteq \ring{K}_{n+1} $; and
    \item $d(\partial K_n,\partial K_{n+1})>0$
\end{itemize}
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]